# Execute expression on List

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a custom IQueryable, to consume a web service.
The webservice has limited functionality about querying.
So what I want is, to query the web service inside my IQueryable and then execute the given expression on the data, comming from the webservice.

My IQueryable implementation looks like this:

```
public class CloudInfoQuery : IQueryable<CloudContentModel>
{
    private string _accessToken;

    public Type ElementType => typeof(CloudContentModel);

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    internal CloudInfoQuery(string accessToken)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        Provider = new CloudInfoProvider(accessToken);
        Expression = Expression.Constant(this);
    }

    internal CloudInfoQuery(string accessToken, IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression) : this(accessToken)
    {
        Provider = provider;
        Expression = expression;
    }

    public IEnumerator<CloudContentModel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<CloudContentModel>>(Expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

My `Execute` in the `IQueryProvider` looks like this:

```
public object Execute(Expression expression)
{
    List<CloudContentModel> cloudContent = GetContentFromWebService(expression);
    return cloudContents.AsQueryable().Provider.Execute(mExpression):
}
```

I am analizing the possible filters from the query and use them for the web service call.
After that I want to execute the expression on the result, so that all filters will apply, that are not supported by the webservice.

But when I do it like this, there will be an endless loop, because of the `Expression = Expression.Constant(this);` in my `CloudInfoQuery`.

I tried to remove the Expression, that is resulting in an endless loop from the expression tree, or to change it with by updating the MethodCallExpression.
But then I will face an `System.ArgumentException: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance`.
Following, what I have tried and results in the exception mentioned above:

Remove the Expression from tree

```
MethodCallExpression mExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;
mExpression = mExpression.Update(expression, mExpression.Arguments.Skip(1));
```

Using an new Expression to update to

```
MethodCallExpression mExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;
mExpression = mExpression.Update(Expression.Constant(cloudContents), mExpression.Arguments.Skip(1));
```

Set a new expression on the top of the expression tree

```
MethodCallExpression mExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;
List<Expression> exs = new List<Expression>();
exs.Add(Expression.Constant(cloudContents));
exs.AddRange(mExpression.Arguments.Skip(1));
mExpression = mExpression.Update(expression, exs);
```

I also tried to prevent the endless loop like this:

```
private IEnumerabe<CloudContentModel> _cloudContents;
public object Execute(Expression expression)
{
    if(_cloudContents != null)
    {
        return _cloudContents;
    }
    List<CloudContentModel> cloudContent = GetContentFromWebService(expression);
    _cloudContents = cloudContents.AsQueryable().Provider.Execute(mExpression);
    return _cloudContents:
}
```

But then the additional filters will not work.
So how can I pass the expression to another List?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, thanks to the Related section I found a solution inspired by this: [How do you transfer the execution of a Expression created by an IQueryable object to a IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503208/how-do-you-transfer-the-execution-of-a-expression-created-by-an-iqueryable-objec?rq=1)

```
public class CloudInfoQuery : IQueryable<CloudContentModel>
{
    private string _accessToken;
    private List<CloudContentModel> _cloudContents = new List<CloudContentModel>();

    public Type ElementType => typeof(CloudContentModel);

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    internal CloudInfoQuery(string accessToken)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        Provider = new CloudInfoProvider(accessToken, _cloudContents);
        Expression = _cloudContents.AsQueryable().Expression;
    }

    internal CloudInfoQuery(string accessToken, IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression) : this(accessToken)
    {
        Provider = provider;
        Expression = expression;
    }

    public IEnumerator<CloudContentModel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<CloudContentModel>>(Expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class CloudInfoProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    private string _accessToken;
    private List<CloudContentModel> _cloudContents = null;

    public CloudInfoProvider(string accessToken, List<CloudContentModel> cloudContent)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        _cloudContents = cloudContent;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new CloudInfoQuery(_accessToken, this, expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return (IQueryable<TElement>)new CloudInfoQuery(_accessToken, this, expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        _cloudContent.Clear();
        _cloudContent.AddRange(GetContentFromWebService(expression));
        return cloudContents.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery(expression):
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return (TResult)Execute(expression);

    }
}
```

The trick was, to use the expression from the same instance, that will later contains the data to filter.

```
Expression = _cloudContents.AsQueryable().Expression;
```